# Should I add another flag as well?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Often times I see on a question a comment like this:
[image]

If I feel that is a duplicate, should I also add a flag? Or should I not, since there's already (probably) a flag on the question? Or, should I just upvote the comment to show support for it?

Comment: Don't take chances. Go ahead and flag as you see fit. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In cases like this, upvote the comment (if it really has merit, because sometimes it doesn't, so evaluate first ;), and you can flag as well to send it up in the flag queue. It helps if multiple people flag the same thing.

Once a question is flagged in this manner, moderators AND 10k+ users are notified, and will usually take action, though we moderators will take action more slowly to allow the community to do its thing.

Comment: It helps when more people flag the same post. :)

Comment: @jokerdino true, let me add that.