# Why do old question appear in the Community Bulletin?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

Occasionally, I notice that one of my questions on meta.askubuntu.com reappears in the Community Bulletin section, despite, when I click on it, there are no apparent changes.
For example, today:
[image]

My question, [Should I add another flag as well?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6188/should-i-add-another-flag-as-well?), is from the 23rd, and I don't think any changes were made. Additionally, there were no extra upvotes on it (although I don't think this bumps questions - correct me if I'm wrong); I know this because I'd [already received](http://meta.askubuntu.com/badges/20/nice-question?userid=107590) the "Nice Question" badge on the 27th.

Why do old questions occasionally "float to the surface" again?

Comment: Please see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/660/when-does-the-community-user-start-bumping-old-questions for an explanation.

Comment: It doesn't meet those criteria, though, because it has an accepted and upvoted answer. For all intents and purposes, it is "closed".

Comment: @guntbert That ... actually has nothing to do with this. The Community Bulletin is not related to the bumping of questions - which, as far as I remember, doesn't really happen on meta anyways.

Comment: See [Nailing it up on your Community Bulletin Board](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The process is described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893):

> If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with hot discussion questions not marked status-completed, scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. **These are picked semi-randomly**. At least one of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.

The list refreshes every 20 minutes or so, and since qualifying meta questions are selected randomly it's not uncommon to see questions pop in and out of the list as chance dictates.